# Enter user data values to Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I am new to Shiny and want to make an app for supporting my basic course on Applied Statistics with visualizations based on real data. The idea is that during the first class students (around 75 persons) will enter their own data, including height, weight and sex, which should be stored somewhere in the app and be used in all other sessions for generating plots and calculating statistics.

I have read tutorials and forums but did not find any example that clarifies this issue. Will be very grateful for any hints or links.

Comment: You could check out `?textInput` for such things. It would be good to show a minimal app where you want to add such functionality. Sex would just need to be a `?selectInput` or possibly `?checkboxInput`. Height and weight could alternatively be included as `?sliderInput`.. really depends on what you want

Comment: I see how organize the GUI/frontend but how to save and then reuse the data?